# Is it possible to use style attribute as default value in databinding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Do you know if it's possible to use theme attributes as default values for databinding?

example:

```
        android:background="@{toolbarColors.backgroundColor, default=@color/color_primary}"
```

turn to :

```
        android:background="@{toolbarColors.backgroundColor, default=?attr/color_primary}"
```

so far i wasn't able to find neither correct notation nor straight answer if it's possible or not. I'm trying to move all internal colour definition to attributes